# Inserting an intesection observer in the right place in order to avoid an enormous network payload

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, intersection-observer

I have an mp3 from an external URL via `<audio></audio>` tag.
As on mobile it takes a few seconds to download before being ready to play, I've added a spinner which reveals the player only once the mp3 is ready to play - so nobody is going to click on play if there's no sound yet.

Everything works, except an ENORMOUS NETWORK PAYLOAD, as the page finish to load only when the first bytes of the mp3 are dowloaded and therefore is ready to play (the mp3 comes in ranges of data - partial content code 206).

So, to avoid the ENORMOUS NETWORK PAYLOAD, I'm thinking to lazy load the mp3, or maybe the whole player, using intersection observer, as the mp3 audio tag is below the fold. But then the mp3 is not downloaded at all.

I've placed the intersection observer after the audio tag is revealed (after the loading spinner is gone), but the mp3 is not downloaded. I've tried everything everywhere, but no success.

I just started to learn some javascript, and I'm not even sure if using the intersectin observer to load the page first, and then the mp3, is a good idea in this case. And anyway I can't make it work, so any help or suggestion is much appreciated. Thank you.

Here's the code:

```
  <div class="player">

    <div class="hide animated" id="player">  {# spinner #}

      <audio data-src="https://some.com/track.mp3"></audio>

    </div> {# spinner #}

      <div class="circle-spin" id="loaderSpinner" role="status"></div> {# spinner #}

   </div>
```

--

```
// SPINNER
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  document.getElementById("loaderSpinner").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("player").classList.remove('hide');
  });


// On the document's DOMContentLoaded event, this script should queries the DOM for audio tag -- so, I guess
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  const mp3 = document.querySelector('audio');

  const io = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      if (!entry.isIntersecting) return;
      entry.target.src = entry.target.getAttribute('data-src');
      io.unobserve(entry.target);
    })
  });

  io.observe(mp3);

});

 
// And here's some customization for audio player controls which starts with load sound via <audio tag
const audioElement = document.querySelector("audio");
const audioCtx = new AudioContext();
const track = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);

// follows Player controls and attributes...

// and finally an event listener that waits for the page to load etc etc
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  // Set times after page load
  setTimes();
// etc etc etc...
```

Comment: Have you tried using the preload attribute of `<audio>` instead? Maybe you won't need that complex logic if you just tell the browser to not preload it :)

Comment: Preload attributes (any) are totally ignored by Safari iOS, and I suspect Android too. And generally they are not well considered by browsers.

Comment: I'm running some test with Safari and iOS last versions, and preload="none" seems to work. Is Safari iOS changing his policy? Still, on developer.apple.com about preload: "There is no guarantee that you get the behavior that you request" and "Safari on iOS never preloads". Anyway, it's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem comes from the fact that your observer will never trigger because your audio has no source.

The audio tag is not even added to the DOM if there is no valid src from the tests I quickly ran.

Also, what you are trying to achieve is already baked in the audio tag. You can use the `preload` attribute to tell the browser if/how it should preload the audio stream.

Values can be:

`auto` The author thinks that the browser should load the entire audio file when the page loads

`metadata` The author thinks that the browser should load only metadata when the page loads

`none` The author thinks that the browser should NOT load the audio file when the page loads

So, for you, I think you'd like none or metadata.

Parts of the answer come from [W3CSchools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_preload.asp)

Comment: Unfortunately, Audio tag Preload attributes (any) are totally ignored by Safari iOS, and I suspect Android too. And generally they are not well considered by browsers. I have to solve this with javascript and, as you noted, I am into a cul de sac.

Comment: I'm running some test with Safari and iOS last versions, and preload="none" seems to work. Is Safari iOS changing his policy? Still, on developer.apple.com about preload: "There is no guarantee that you get the behavior that you request" and "Safari on iOS never preloads". Anyway, it's working. Thanks @Salketer

Comment: According to CanIUse, it is supported by 96% of the internet users... The only catch here is that the preload attribute is a HINT to the browser, exact rules on how the browser handles it may be hard to find and may even differ from time to time...